# Why is each snow flake different?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, geometry, ice

What are the factors that determine the patterns of snow flake formation? Would pressure and the rate at which a snow flake freezes make a difference? Does the PH and impurities make a change in the snow flakes structure?

[image: http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1492634/thumbs/o-4-900.jpg?1]

http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1492620/thumbs/o-SNOW-900.jpg?6
[image]

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8545/8629790711_eef26cd72b_c.jpg
[image]

http://www.snowcrystals.com/guide/sampler.jpg
[image]

Comment: Jen -- you've been around long enough, and I've told you this several times before -- provide citations/credit for the pictures you use in your posts and make sure you are following the licenses of said images.

Comment: Images edited out pending a response to @tpg2114 .

Comment: I really do recommend Google: http://earthsky.org/earth/how-do-snowflakes-get-their-shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The shape and formation of snow crystals is dependent on the temperature and humidity of the air layers in which they are formed.**  It follows that there is a wide range of possible crystal types based on possible meteorological conditions.

Typically, finer grained snowflakes are formed in colder, dryer air.  Coarse grained snowflakes are formed in warmer, more humid air (where more moisture exists).  [Professor Kenneth G. Libbrecht's research](http://snowcrystals.com/) is the best resource Ive come across - it discusses snowflake formation, driving conditions, and much more.

[image: Snow Conditions]

Once snowflakes fall to ground, they deform/metamorphasize into reduced crystal shapes (again based on mechanical action and meteorological conditions) over time - this process is beyond the scope of the question but its covered extensively in the cited works.

As an aside, with great importance to the study of friction/travel on snow surfaces: The relatively high value of hardness at temperatures close to snow’s melting point is an important material property that contributes to snow's strength and low coefficient of friction.  The hardness of snow increases linearly from about -40 ̊ C up to its melting point (0 ̊ C) (Tusima, K.). But, its important to distinguish the hardness at a crystalline scale (~1mm) and macro scale (larger snow samples).  Small scale hardness is of importance for friction.  Large scale hardness is of importance for shear and loading strengths .

---

Some of the best resources on snow and snow friction that Im aware of:

- [SWIX (Racing Manual)](http://www.swixsport.com/content/download/1554/206073/version/8/file/PRV1523E+XC+Racing+English.pdf)
- [A Review of the Processes That
  Control Snow Friction](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a252362.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pressure and freeze rate as well as other factors influence snow flake patterns. Snow flake formation is a nonlinear nonequilibrium process in which a liquid makes a phase transition to a crystalline solid. Such processes usually result in unique fractal patterns.